# Read a category attribute from title.phtml in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, php-7.2

I have found a lot of examples on how to create an extra attribute for the categories. I want to create a text field for adding a different H1 - instead of using the category name as the headings, on the category pages.

But how can I fetch the attribute from the title.phtml file?

```
(\app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Theme\templates\html\title.phtml)
```

I have this to check if on a category page in title.phtml:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
/*
 * Check if on product page
 * ------------------------
 */
if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
...
}
?>
```

Comment: You want your custom field's value from category in title.phtml file ?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace the H1 title with the value in the attribute field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
/*
 * Check if on product page
 * ------------------------
 */
if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    $customAttributeValue = $category->getData('custom_attribute'); //here you can replace your attribute code with 'custom_attribute'.
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if this works for you @Alldo

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ran into some problem with the attribute I want to test, they didn't become saved store view wise, need to fix that before i can test your solution :-) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295865/category-attribute-not-saved-to-store-views-i-magento-2-3-3

Comment: Works perfect, thank you @Kishan Savaliya

Comment: You're welcome Buddy. :)