# Solved: How to make category attribute saved store wise in Magento 2.3.3, not only global?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

How can I make custom category attributes being saved in to different store views, in Magento 2.3.3, and not only global?

Change ***'global' => 1***  to ***'global' => 0*** doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'custom_category_field',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Category Custom field',
                'input' => 'text',
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Working example efter help from @Haijerome

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'category_heading',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Category Heading',
                'input' => 'text',
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Did you saved value for your custom attribute store wise ? and check that ? Because I created one attribute and saved that store wise and that is working but "Use Default Value" checkbox only not coming in my case.

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't work. I installed the custom module with scope set to 0. But when that didn't work I changed to 1 and ran setup upgrade again, still no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Category entity attributes can be set to the following scopes. [Source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/ScopedAttributeInterface.php)

```
const SCOPE_STORE = 0;
const SCOPE_GLOBAL = 1;
const SCOPE_WEBSITE = 2;
```

You can use set the '**global**' value to 
Store scope by using the code below (but I can see you have used 0 already. Try to upgrade your data and set the global value of the attribute as given below )

> Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not sure exactly what to do. Where should I put that line of code @Haijerome? Sorry for not understanding you :-)

Comment: I figured it out and it's working, thank you!

Comment: @Alldo glad that you get it done. Sorry that i was not on my machine at that time to give you the exact piece of code.